# Keycloak Custom Reset Credential flow

Tags: keycloak

[image]I would like to change the reset credentials flow, adding the username password form after reset password form.

In the administration console, the following “custom reset credential” flow has been created:

However, the username password form is displayed before the reset password form.

Why is the username password form displayed before the reset password form, while it appears after in the sequence of flow actions ?

Thanks for your help !

Need a solution for this I want to redirect to login page after reset credentials

Comment: Facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for this?